# ASP.NET Core Webservice as localhost functional, but in IIS it gives an 404 Not Found Error

Tags: c#, angular, iis, asp.net-core

I have a problem with my ASP.NET Core Web Service.

I needed JWT for Authentication in my Angular project. That's why I made a service where the user needs to be checked, if he is authorized. I made it with .NET Core, because I have IIS Server.

When I run it locally with "dotnet run" I can make get or put requests locally. I tested it also in YARC plugin of Google Chrome by making a POST request with Payload (JSON with 2 key value pairs).

I uploaded the service in IIS Server, started it, gave the url (this time with the domain of server where IIS located) on YARC plugin in my local maschine again for POST request with the same payload. It gives me 404-Not Found Error.

Functional local url is: http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login

URL for IIS: http://myIISMachine:7471/api/auth/login (Port number is in the launchSettings.json file as well)

ConfigureServices function in my Startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

        ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5000",
        ValidAudience = "http://localhost:5000",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MySecretKey"))
    };
});

services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().Build();
    });
});

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

And Configure function:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors("EnableCORS");

        app.UseAuthentication();

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

launchSettings.json file:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false, 
"anonymousAuthentication": true, 
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:7471",
  "sslPort": 44365
}
},
"profiles": {
 "IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/values",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"webapplication": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/values",
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
}
}
```

What am I doing here wrong? Or maybe is this something to do with the settings in IIS server? Could you help me please?

Comment: Where is `steropes-02` coming from? Your IIS settings show an application url with `localhost`.

Comment: Steropes is my server domain where iis located.

Comment: Its not the setting of iis. It is the setting of my webservice

Comment: Please learn some IIS basics. Site bindings decide what URL you use, and launchSettings.json is neglected.

Comment: I only gave the port number (7471) in bindings. When I gave only the serverdomain with this portnumber in browser (without 'api/auth/login'), it shows me the directory of the files of my service. Connection with the service in iis is not the problem. The problem is making the post (or any other) request with the same service on iis.

Comment: You probably should use FRT to learn more about the 404, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis